# When no record associated with the given id, which action should the action method do? Returning NoFound view or redirecting to NoFound action method?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In `Details`, `Edit`, `Delete` action methods we have `id` parameter to retrieve the corresponding record from the database.

If no record corresponds to the `id`, we have 2 choices:

> The executing action method returns a
>   specific view, which is usually named as
>   `NoFound.cshtml` under `Views\Shared`
>   directory, to inform the user that the
>   `id` is not valid.

or

> The executing action method redirect
>   the user to a specific action method,
>   for example `public ActionResult
>   NoFound (string message)`, to inform
>   the user about the issue.

My question is:
When no record associated with the given id, which action should the action method do? Returning `NoFound` view or redirecting to `NoFound` action method?

**Edit 1**
I need  reasons from technical point of view such as security and performance.

Answer (score 9):

It's all personal preference. In my opinion though, the real thing that should happen in this situation is a 404 response code should be sent back to the client. You can have custom 404 pages that give you the best of both worlds.

Comment: +1 Certainly for Details a 404 Not Found makes the most sense here. For Edit and Delete, I'm wavering between a 404 or possibly a 405 "Method Not Allowed" (http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.6) as you can't delete or edit a non-existent resource, but to adhere to the spec, you must send an Allows header with the allowed methods, so 404 might be more sensible.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to **Step 5** on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619895/how-can-i-properly-handle-404s-in-asp-net-mvc/2577095#2577095) - custom 404, proper 404 response code, proper handling of the "item not found" case.

Answer (score 0):

I would return a "Not found" view, because this way an URL with ID could be stored in favorites and will became valid when record with this ID will be available.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend still returning a 404 error. The order of the parameters in the route is irrelevant, some people prefer {controller}/{action}/{id}, in some cases {controller}/{id}/{action} might make more sense. In either case if all three parameters are required for it to be considered a valid request and one is missing you should return a 404. It will also make testing your site much easier as if you return a view it will have a result code of 200 and make it much more difficult to track down broken links. 404 errors are universally recognized as a problem when doing site analysis.